# How can I re-enable unicode support?

Tags: team-fortress-2

A recent patch, I'm not sure which, has broken the unicode support within my Steam copy of TF2. Server names with non-Roman characters don't show. I don't even have umlauts which is silly considering that you need them to write **Übercharge**.

Some Googling didn't turn up anything recent, just a few complaints from 2009. I'm sure it's a TF2 only problem, and have made no other recent changes to my system.

How can I restore unicode support to my copy of TF2?

Comment: @Steve V.: Mmmph mhrhhrmph.

Comment: The question is right there: "How can I restore unicode support to my copy of TF2?"

Comment: Ask 3 of your friends that play TF2. Do they experience the same problem as you are?

Comment: Relevant: [patches](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1629850) and [old bugs](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1914748).

Comment: I'm deleting local content and re-downloading. Will see if that fixes it. Previously my local content was verified as complete, no errors, so... :-/

Comment: Welp, that didn't work. I have CHN support but not Korean. Bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

First search for a server outside of the TF2 client, use sites such as [Gametracker](http://www.gametracker.com/search/tf2/US/) or [Game-Monitor](http://www.game-monitor.com/GameSearch/tf2/Team_Fortress_2.html).  Then instead of relying on unicode support for server connections in TF2, use the IP address on the server you want to connect to.